# strange error in main and incorrect reading of a vector

Tags: c++

hi I was writing a code where near the vectors it returns true if they are placed in ascending order otherwise false, when I try to start the code it gives me this error that I cannot understand

```
main.cpp:9:5: error: conflicting types for 'main'
int main(int, const char *[]) {
    ^
./solution.cpp:30:5: note: previous definition is here
int main()
    ^
1 error generated.
```

the other error happens in the vector inAscOrder_3 in which it should return false but I don't understand why it doesn't return it.

the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
bool isAscOrder(vector<int> arr)
{
    int size_array = arr.size()-1;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < size_array; j++)
    {
        if (min == 0)
        {
            min = arr[j];
            max = arr[j];
        }

        if (arr[j] > min)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(arr[j]<min)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> inAscOrder_1 = {1, 2, 4, 7, 19}; // returns true
    vector<int> inAscOrder_2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // returns true
    vector<int> inAscOrder_3 = { 1, 6, 10, 18, 2, 4, 20 }; // returns false
    vector<int> inAscOrder_4 = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }; // returns false because the numbers are in DESCENDING order


    //test 1

    if (isAscOrder(inAscOrder_1) == true)
    {
        cout << "test #1 passed! " << endl;;
    }
    if (isAscOrder(inAscOrder_2) == true)
    {
        cout << "test #2 passed! "<<endl;
    }
    if (isAscOrder(inAscOrder_3) == false)
    {
        cout << "test #3 passed! "<<endl;
    }
    if (isAscOrder(inAscOrder_4) == false)
    {
        cout << "test #4 passed! ";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you run your code?

Comment: You have two files, "main.cpp" and "solution.cpp". Only one of them should contain a main function. (Or you just shouldn't compile them together into a single binary.)

Comment: www.codewars.com I have to start it on this site

Comment: AFAIK codewars provides large part of common implementation including `main`. Task should specify what kind of function you should provide.

Comment: In `isAscOrder()` you set `min` (and the unused `max` variable) on the 1st iteration of your loop - and on the next iteration, if the value is greater than min you instantly return true. You should be going through the array, returning `false` if you find a value less than `arr[j-1]`. Also, why set `size_array` to `arr.size() - 1`. You'll miss out the last element in the array since your loop condition is `j < size_array`.

Comment: It appears you have two `main()` functions, one in `main.cpp` and the other in `solution.cpp`.   A program is only allowed to have one `main()` function, so remove one from your project (e.g. move it to another source file that is not included in the build of your program).    Also, one of the specifications supported by the standard is `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or (equivalently) `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.     Your `main()` that has a specification `int main(int, const char *[])` is different - while some implementations may support it, others may not - so remove the `const`.

Comment: @Enk17_  -- FYI:  `bool isAscOrder(vector<int> arr) { return std::is_sorted(arr.begin(), arr.end()); }`  It is a one-line solution.

Comment: Or you could just use `std::is_sorted(inAscOrder_1.begin(), inAscOrder_1.end())` and have an actual one-line solution without abstracting it behind a non-templated function call for no reason.

We get it, many things can be done with the pre-existing standard library functions - but introducing iterators isn't helpful when you don't know the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your average C++ program, the `main` function is the **singular entry and exit point** for the program. When your executable is called, the program starts at `main`, and once `main` returns, the program releases all of its allocated resources and is terminated.

Your first issue arises because you have multiple declarations of the `main` function; the first is located at `main.cpp:9:5`, and the second is located at `solution.cpp:30:5`

As for your second issue, your function does not do what you think it does; any correlation between your expected outputs and the real outputs are pure coincidence.

```cpp
bool isAscOrder(vector<int> arr)
{
    // This gets the size of your vector, then subtracts 1.
    //  size_array is now the index of the last element in the vector,
    //  and can be accessed with arr[size_array] without throwing an exception.
    int size_array = arr.size()-1;

    int min = 0;
    int max = 0; //< you never actually read the value from this

    // This condition is true until (j == size_array), and once it is the for loop breaks the loop.  
    //  Keep in mind, size_array is currently set to the index of the last ELEMENT in your vector;
    //  That means you're always skipping the last element in the vector.
    // You can avoid this by checking either ( j < arr.size() ) or ( j <= size_array )
    //                ▼
    for (int j = 0; j < size_array; j++)
    {
        // This is always triggered on the first loop because min is always set to 0 the first time.
        //  if every number in the vector is 0 (except for the last one),
        //  then this will trigger every single time.
        //  ▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼
        if (min == 0)
        {
        //      ▼         Sets min to the value at arr[j]
            min = arr[j];
            max = arr[j];
        //      ▲         Sets max to the value at arr[j],
        //                 so max is now equal to min.
        //                For tests 1-3, that value is `1`;
        //                 for test 4, that value is `9`

        // Here we check if the value at arr[j] is greater than min, and if it is-
        //  -we immediately break from the for loop and return true.
        if (arr[j] > min)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Here we check if the value at arr[j] is less than min, and if it is-
        //  -we immediately break from the for loop and return false.
        if(arr[j]<min)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //< we never reach this point a second time unless ( arr[0] == arr[1] )
    }
    //< This is only ever reached if every element of arr except for
    //  the last one is set to the same number.
    return false;
}
```

As an example of what this function is doing, I debugged it for you:

[image]

As you can see, the function returned true on the second loop; this is because `arr[1]`*(`2`)* is greater than `min`*(`1`)*.

- `inAscOrder_1`

  - Returns true when `j == 1`, because `inAscOrder_1[1] == 2`, and `2 > 1`
- `inAscOrder_2`

  - Returns true when `j == 1`, because `inAscOrder_2[1] == 2`, and `2 > 1`
- `inAscOrder_3`

  - Returns true when `j == 1`, because `inAscOrder_3[1] == 6`, and `6 > 1`
- `inAscOrder_4`

  - Returns false when `j == 1`, because `inAscOrder_4[1] == 8`, and `8 < 9`

This is a working example of what your function should be doing:

```cpp
bool isAscOrder(vector<int> arr)
{
    if (arr.size() < 2) //< make sure arr[1] exists
        return false;

    // Start at 1    Don't skip the last element
    //          ▼    ▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼
    for (int i{ 1 }; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        // Check if arr[i] is less than or equal to arr[i - 1], this is
        //  why we started at 1 instead of 0; to prevent accessing arr[-1]
        //      ▼         ▼▼▼▼▼
        if (arr[i] <= arr[i - 1])
            return false;
        // This approach works because if the sequence is in ascending order,
        //  each number in arr is never less than the previous one. (except for arr[0], which doesn't have a previous number)
    }

    return true;
}
```

You can allow a vector with repeated numbers to return true with this variant:

```cpp
bool isAscOrder(vector<int> arr, bool allowRepeats = false)
{
    if (arr.size() < 2) //< make sure arr[1] exists
        return false;

    for (int i{ 1 }; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        if (allowRepeats
             ? ( arr[i] <  arr[i - 1] ) //< when allowing repeats, return false if the current element is less than the previous one.
             : ( arr[i] <= arr[i - 1] ) //< when disallowing repeats, return false if the current element is less than or equal to the previous one.
           )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

When you're writing C++ code, having access to a debugger is incredibly important; if you're on Windows you can download and use [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) for free.

Comment: FYI, [std::is_sorted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) does everything that your code is attempting to do.

Comment: It does, but you don't learn very much from using `std::is_sorted`

Comment: *but you don't learn very much from using std::is_sorted* -- You learn 1) That functions already exist to accomplish the goal, without bugs,  2) You learn that using such functions gets your application development moving faster, 3) You learn that not knowing, or not being aware of such functions, lessens your chances of finding employment as a C++ programmer.

Comment: With that attitude, in a few generations no one is going to know how to do anything anymore...

Comment: *no one is going to know how to do anything anymore* -- The program isn't going to magically write itself by using `std::is_sorted` and other functions.  You still have to write the program, regardless.  So saying "not know how to do anything", many programs that use STL containers and algorithms are still sophisticated enough that a beginner or even intermediate could not even consider writing a program that sophisticated.  I work on one now, and it is replacing all of the "raw loops" with the proper set of algorithm functions and containers.

Comment: While I wholeheartedly agree that people should use the STL wherever possible *in production code*, I stand by learning things the old way first.

IMO if you don't have a basic understanding of how an STL function works, you shouldn't use it. Doing so anyway is a great way to reinforce bad habits since you don't actually get what **all of** your own code is doing.

After all, it's not like OP is writing production code yet - they're still learning how to iterate over the indexes of an array, which is much more important and is transferable between languages whereas the STL is not.